# UV - scaling with individual origins is not working when vertices touch each other

Tags: uv, transforms, uv-image-editor

In my current Blender version with the "UV/Image Editor" I use "individual origins" and I disabled "sticky selection". It works when scaling selected faces that don't touch each other, but when I have a selection of faces connected to each other by a vertex or vertices, the scaling becomes like a "median point" type of scaling.

[image]

Yet when I do this in 2.79 it keeps the "individual origin" type of scaling, so is it a bug or a feature that can be disabled or is there an addon to get around this? Thank you for helping.

Comment: The logic baffles me, too... It works if you split the edges in the geometry..but I don't see why you should have to, if you've set seams.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug :). It behaves unpredictably, depending on selection order, and other stuff.

Comment: Posted as a bug https://developer.blender.org/T85644 ... so let see what it is.

Comment: @vklidu I tried to do as you said/shown in the description and GIF with 2.79 in which you succeeded. Though during testing I had the same issue you encountered but with 2.79 instead. Yet the only way I was able to get it to work the way you did it was by either using edge split or vertices split. Yet since you didn't specify that, all that I can suggest is that you can either list on here step by step what you did in 2.79 to get it to work so that we all can see/try it or you can do the 2.79 method you tried exactly step by step in the new blender version. Maybe even provide a 2.79 Blend file.